# copy file from installshield in c# code

Tags: c#, installshield

I want to load file (ocx file) to my installer and I want that the installer will run a c# code that will copy the file to one of the folders: systm32 or sysWOW64 (according to the O.S that the installer will run on it).
How can I load the file to installshield (where I need to save it in the project)?
How can I run the C# code (from the installshield) and how to pass it the file?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I know how to run exe file in the installshield, but I don't know how  to cop the file to the folder so my exe file will use it.